# How to have a cross tabulation for categorical data in Pandas (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab

I have the following code for example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dtype="category")
df["Gender"]=np.random.randint(2, size=100)
df["Q1"] = np.random.randint(3, size=100)
df["Q2"] = np.random.randint(3, size=100)
df["Q3"] = np.random.randint(3, size=100)
df[["Gender", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]] = df[["Gender", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]].astype('category')
pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=["Gender"])
```

I want to have a pivot table with percentages over gender for all the other columns. Infact, like the follwing.

[image]

How to achieve this?

The above code gives an error saying that 
`No numeric types to aggregate`

I dont have any numerical columns. I just want to find the frequency in each category under male and female and find the percentage of them over male and female respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by your question, you can use the `pd.crosstab` to make the cross tabulation you need.

You just need to do a quick **preprocessing** with your data, which is to `melt` and convert `Q` columns to rows (see details below):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='Gender', 
         value_vars=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'], 
         var_name='Question', value_name='Answer' )
```

Then you can use `pd.crosstab` and calculate percentage as needed (here the percentage for each `Question` per `Gender` per `Answer` is shown)

```
pd.crosstab(df.Question, columns=[df.Gender, df.Answer]).apply(lambda row: row/row.sum(), axis=1)
```

```
Gender       0                 1            
Answer       0     1     2     0     1     2
Question                                    
Q1        0.13  0.18  0.18  0.13  0.19  0.19
Q2        0.09  0.21  0.19  0.22  0.13  0.16
Q3        0.19  0.10  0.20  0.16  0.18  0.17
```

---

**Details**

`df.head()`

```
  Gender Q1 Q2 Q3
0      1  0  2  0
1      1  0  0  1
2      0  2  0  2
3      0  0  2  0
4      0  1  1  1
```

`df.melt().head()`

```
  Gender Question Answer
0      1       Q1      0
1      1       Q1      0
2      0       Q1      2
3      0       Q1      0
4      0       Q1      1
```

Comment: Amazing...Thanks a lot for the answer. One quick question. Can I do the percentage of answer groupby males and females separately?

Comment: I believe if you change the order of columns in `pd.crosstab` function, you get what you are looking for.. `columns=[df.Answer, df.Gender]`

Comment: no..no..thats not what i wanted..this changes the cross tabulation. The cross tab what you have got is the one I wanted but the percentages has be calcuated from row sum of male and row sum of female respecviely

Comment: I think it is something to do with the .apply method

Comment: in the row first three columns has to be divided by its  row sum and the next three columns also has be divided by its row sum..

Comment: That is not what you are showing as your expected results

Comment: Yeah..Thats true... I actually want to change that to male and female percentage.